# meta-oe of meta-openembedded vs meta of Poky

Tags: yocto, bitbake

What is the difference between meta-oe of meta-openembedded layer and meta of poky layer

https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded

https://git.yoctoproject.org/git/poky

I am looking into building yocto for raspberry pi3

https://git.yoctoproject.org/git/meta-raspberrypi

This layer depends on meta-openembedded layers ( meta-oe, meta-multimedia, meta-networking, meta-python)

I thought meta-oe layer is same as meta of poky and i didn't include it in bblayers.conf and it fails with dependency error

```
ERROR: Layer 'networking-layer' depends on layer 'openembedded-layer', but this layer is not enabled in your configuration
ERROR: Layer 'meta-python' depends on layer 'openembedded-layer', but this layer is not enabled in your configuration
```

Can you please help us understand the difference between meta-oe of meta-openembedded and meta of poky

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are indeed two different layers.

1. the 'meta' folder in the poky repository corresponds to the Openembedded Core layer, e.g. https://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/. OE Core includes the main components/recipes that are widely used for any configuration.
2. the 'meta-oe' folder in meta-openembedded is another layer typically called the 'openembedded' layer. meta-oe contains a large amount of additional recipes.

The poky repository is an aggregation of several repositories: openembedded-core, bitbake, meta-poky and yocto-docs.