# Can we use both openembedded-core & meta-openembedded submodules together. or openembedded-core is now subset of meta-openembedded

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, openembedded

I want to implement rootfs using OverlayFS from https://github.com/cmhe/meta-readonly-rootfs-overlay. This project's basic dependencies are:

> ```
> URI: git://git.openembedded.org/bitbake
> branch: krogoth
>
> URI: git://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core
> layers: meta
> branch: krogoth
> ```

However as per my application requirements, I am already using `meta-openembedded` layer (replacing this will cause uncertain changes, for rpi based system).

Can I use `openembedded-core` and `meta-openembedded` simultaneously in same build configuration, in order to use this OverlayFS layer?

Comment: Hey! I wasn't aware of openembedded-core untill now.. from their doc it says it only supports emulated machines... so likely no RPI... it also looks like it some files might already be duplicates from differend meta-openembedded layers... if I were you I'd try to build without openembedded-core and see if that works. Keep me posted, I'm interested in the result

Comment: Hey Loic ! I have built the image successfully using only meta-openembedded. But, It is not showing any partitions for read write and read only file systems in root directory designated folder. Do you have any idea how to test it? That will be a great help.

Comment: Well, on that point I'm a bit out of my depth... My understanding is you need to write an initscript to have the root and rootrw partitions correctly loading. If you have the initscript, I suppose doing a lsblk should show somthing (idk what exactly) on /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 that might indicate that root and rootrw are set correctly... Hope that helps and that I'm not just suggesting things you already tired.

Comment: Thank you! Currently I'm busy with another project. As soon as I will try this I will update it here. I believe it will work properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/60784126/3685851? If you're using Yocto, the `meta` directory in Poky satisfies the `layers: meta` requirement of this project.since it is a built-in version of oe-core. More info on that here: https://www.yoctoproject.org/software-overview/reference-distribution/